# What should maven M2_Home be?

Tags: maven

- I installed maven with `sudo apt install maven`
- Then, from [this repo](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-maven) ran `mvn clean install`.
- I got the following error

```
[ERROR] org.eclipse.xtext.maven.plugin.XtextGeneratorIT  Time elapsed: 4.246 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Maven home not found. Tried to call 'mvn'.
Consider to set the envVar 'M2_HOME' or System property 'maven.home'.
Current settings are: maven.home=null M2_HOME=null
```

What should my `M2_HOME` be??? I typed `mvn --version` to get a clue:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_IL, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-109-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

But I'm not sure what to do now. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't be set at all cause it's not needed. Only the entry in your path with the bin directory  of the apache maven distribution...and of course JAVA_HOME to define which java you are using .....Why do such IT need the setting of M2_HOME? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M2_HOME` is a home of Maven. It should be the root directory of your maven installation/binaries. It is used by script `mvn` (correspondingly mvn.bat on Windows).

Comment: so just run `which mvn` and set it there?

Comment: Set it as the Environment Variable, which points to the root of your maven folder. `Which mvn` may return more than one result, but you can give it a try, yes. Which OS you're using?